# How to design a circuit for multiple 12 V loads using one battery?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, fan, heater, thermostat

How can I connect multiple 12 V loads to this 12 V, 2600 mAh [Li-ion battery](https://quartzcomponents.com/products/12v-2600-mah-rechargeable-lithium-battery-pack-with-warranty-includes-bms-for-gps-cctv-industrial-and-commercial-application?_pos=5&_sid=9fa0d0658&_ss=r) without damaging it?

- 12 VDC cartridge heater
- 12 VDC fan
- 12 VDC thermostat

Comment: Total up the currents for your loads, if they are under 2.6A you are ok.

Comment: Question on the use of electronic devices are off topic and will likely result in closure. Try to rephrase as a design question.

Comment: How to Connect?

Comment: How much current does each load require?

Comment: @Rocky connect one wire from the heater to one battery terminal ... connect the other wire from the heater to the other battery terminal ... repeat for the fan ... the thermostat is probably not a load, so it is unclear why you are asking about it ... you never said what you expect the circuit to do

Comment: Did not able to understand
Kindly make a sketch
12 VDC cartridge heater
12 VDC fan
12 VDC thermostat

Comment: These are the products -https://www.electronicscomp.com/12v-40w-ceramic-cartridge-heater

Comment: https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwjsirSJgIP9AhUrv0sFHVA1BcAYABAMGgJzZg&sig=AOD64_2IEWbriJMTu5Lvg_aadQUPR9-FLw&ctype=5&q=&ved=2ahUKEwie6qyJgIP9AhW0t2MGHTAOC_8Qww8oAnoECAYQDA&adurl=https://www.amazon.in/xcluma-TR01Temperature-Controller-Indicators-Thermometer/dp/B081KZHPQZ

Comment: Power supply- https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwiEqf6VgIP9AhXBRCsKHTJ8CGIYABAcGgJzZg&sig=AOD64_0IZdPgf0Pfh05FSj8ytewI49qVxw&ctype=5&q=&ved=2ahUKEwid3vaVgIP9AhUYiWMGHZm9AYYQ9aACKAB6BAgHEHM&adurl=

Comment: How to make a single switch device using a single 12v battary
just to switch on and 3 devices are on at a time

Comment: @Rocky You cant. your cartridge heater alone draws more current than your battery can safely provide.

Answer (score 1):

Your cartridge heater alone is rated at 40W which means that it draws 3.33A at 12V. Your battery can safely supply a maximum current of 2.6A which is less than the current drawn by the cartridge heater. Hence, you can not power them using this battery.

Comment: What will be the alternative? As less wattage heater

Comment: You can get a battery that can supply more current.